# img center, round and center in a div

Tags: html, css, image, ionic2

I am stack with a css issue. 
I would like my picture center in a div (the red one) with a size 50% of the div and also perfectly round...

here is my html code :

```
<ion-content class="masters">
  <ion-row>
    <div class="profil-img">
      <img src="../../assets/img/tennis-club.jpeg" alt="">
    </div>
  </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

here is my css code :

```
.profil-img img{
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid white;
   // position:absolute;
    max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.profil-img{
border: 2px solid black;
}
```

and here the result : 
[image]

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I've tried out many things and now i got a solution.
Could this solve your Problem?

```css
.red {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #f00;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
.profil-img {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(calc(-50% - 3px)) translateX(calc(-50% - 3px));
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.profil-img > img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <div class="profil-img">
    <img src="https://cdn.transportbox-katzen.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/katze-gewohnheitstier.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! this work but since I am in a ionic 2 app I don't use `class="red"` I have an ion-grid.. so the only issue now is that my picture is a perfect circle.. @UfguFufullu

Comment: Probably because my image does not have the same height and width.. do you have an idea how I can turn it to circle, whatever the heigth/width... ? @UfguFufullu

Comment: The `.profil-img` class will always has the same width-height-ratio as the parent (in this example like `.red`). As you wanted the `.profil-img` got the half of width and height of the parent `div`. If you want to get another ratio you have to change the parents width or height or both of them @YLM

Answer (score 1):

For perfectly round image, you have to specify the same width and height for the image.

```
.profil-img img{
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid white;
    display: inline-block;
    height:200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

If you want the image to be centered vertically and horizontally, you may try the following:

```
.profil-img img{
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid white;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    top: 50%;
   left: 50%; 
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
   -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
    height:200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Please let me know if it worked for you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering @SreenathPG ! So if I specify the same width and height the image is perfectly round, thanks for that. But actually the picture is bigger than my div (can I give a % of my div size ? and still have a perfect circle ?), secondly, with this code my picture is stack on the left side.. If you have ideas/solutions.. thanks

Comment: yes you can give width 50% of that div. I could help you with that if you could just  post a working fiddle. Atleast can you give me link of image

Comment: May i know which is this div with black border??

Comment: My bad.. confused with other post.. I edit your post.. obviously there is no black border in your code..

Comment: trying giving position: relative;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145696/discussion-between-sreenathpg-and-ylm).